# Unable to get set-cookie value from header with axios reactjs

Tags: reactjs, rest, cookies, axios, create-react-app

I am consuming REST APIs from react app. My ASP .NET web api server is returning cookies in response to axios get request but i am **UNABLE** to get set-cookie header from the response. BOTH app and api are running locally. 
I can see the cookies in postman and in the browser window, but not in react app. Please help me sort it out.

**React app**

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => {
        axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.get('https://localhost:44399/api/Cross/GetTest')
                .then(response => {
                    var value = response.headers["set-cookie"] // it is always undefined
                });
        });
    };
```

**REST APIs**

```
public class CrossOrigenController : BaseApiController
    {
        [Route("api/Cross/GetTest")]
        [System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get()
        {
            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("session-id", DateTime.Now.ToString());
            cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1);
            cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
            cookie.Path = "/";
            cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            cookie.Secure = false;
            resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
            return resp;
        }
    }
```

**Cores Enabled** in WebApiConfig

```
config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:3000", "*", "*") { SupportsCredentials = true });
```

Comment: Do you see  it when `console.log(response.headers);`?

Comment: yeah, there is no such header value.

Comment: Is `httpOnly` set to on on your server?

Comment: Thank you @felixmosh for the response. both HttpOnly and Secure are set to false.

Comment: Is this helped?

Comment: nah man, i have tried everything, still no differnce.

Comment: Why do you need this header? if you can remove the httpOnly, you can access the cookie value from `document.cookie`

Comment: Thank you @felixmosh. I was expecting it somewhere in the headers. but i am okay with document.cookie as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent 6 hours trying to find it in headers but with some help from @felixmosh, you can see it in `document.cookie`.